# AQW610EAH-PhotoMos Relay

Tags: relay, components, photodiode, optoelectronics

Can we apply voltage across 1 and 2 pins to control normally closed (N.C) and to pins 3 and 4 for normally open (N.O) at the same time in AQW610EAH ICs (pin diagram of that IC above)? Or only one N.C or N.O can be controlled at a time and the other will operate normally? I have read its datasheet and searched for operation, but I still have no idea. Any one that knows about this IC or something else similar please help!!

[image: Pin Diagram]

Answer (score 0):

They are independent and you would need a current limiting resistor with applied voltage.

Include link to [datasheet](https://www3.panasonic.biz/ac/e_download/control/relay/photomos/catalog/semi_eng_ge1a1b_aqw61_e.pdf) next time pls.